# Design pattern to implement a graph like flow of execution or AWS Step Function

Tags: java, design-patterns

1 line question - Is there a design pattern/mechanism to implement AWS Step functions in Java where each graph-node can be one logical task which takes a input context object, and based on the processing result, moves over to the next logical task?

Detailed question:
I have a business requirement where given few input details, there can be a set of rules that needs to be checked/run for the input. Each rule can have X possible results. Based on the result, the execution should flow into the next rule/terminal node.

Visually it can look something like this:

```
ContextObject --- [ Node1 ] --- TypeA --- [ Rule1 ]
                     |                       |____ ResultX ---- [ TerminalNode1 ]
                    TypeB                    |____ ResultY ---- [ TerminalNode2 ]
                     |
                   [ Rule1 ] -- ResultX -- [ Rule3 ] ---- ResultA --- [ TerminalNode 3 ]
                     |                        |___________ ResultB --- [ TerminalNode4 ]
                     |
                     |_________ ResultY -- [ Action1 ] ---- ResultC --- [ TerminalNode 5 ]
```

Note on how I also wanted to re-use any given Node across different areas of the graph. Each node will certainly only have a specific possible branch (result) coming out of it, but where it should go to next needs to be configurable and the previous branch result (eg, TypeA and TypeB) can also influence subsequent node's next node destination. Example, ResultX in `Rule1` led to `TerminalNode1` for the TypeA initiated chain, but led to `Rule3` in `TypeB` initiated chain.

Initial idea is to have an interface `Node` such as this:

```
public interace Node {
  GraphResponse execute(Ctxt context);
}
```

The implementations of the above Node will all have a unique node name defined as a String. It will run it's `execute()` function and determine it's results. It can add necessary data in the input `Ctxt` object before calling the next node's `execute` method:

```
public class Rule1 implements Node {
 public String Rule1;
 
 public GraphResponse execute(Ctxt ctxt) {
   // does one logical thing
   NextNodeFactory.getNextNode(<some List of String or a POJO - potentially containing the 
     branch/results of previous nodes. Completely configurable.>).execute();
  }
}
```

And as seen above, there will be a `NextNodeFactory` class which will have the entire Graph logically created when it's instantiated:

```
public class NextNodeFactory {
  
  Map<String, Node> Map = {
    ("potential immutable list of String results/POJO - 1", new Rule1());
    ("potential immutable list of String results/POJO - 2", new Rule2());
    ("potential immutable list of String results/POJO - 3", new TerminalNode1());
    ("TerminalNode1", new TerminalNode1());
  };

  getNextNode(<input list of string, or some POJO>) {
     return nodeMap.getOrDefault(<input>, "defaultTerminalNode");
  }
}
```

This is a very high level idea which is not tried and tested. I wanted to understand if there is anything potentially simpler than this. If not, how scalable is the above idea? What are the potential issues that can come up? For now, it does seem easier to add a new rule/action if I wanted to in future. I will only need to create the rule/action class and make changes to my map representing the graph.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you look at ReactiveX, or use an external orchestration framework like AWS CodePipeline w/ SQS to run multiple functions, and pass inputs/outputs between them

Comment: @OneCricketeer unfortunately using any external resource seems out of the question as this entire graph execution needs to be completed as soon as possible and give a real-time execution response. Each "node" here is going to be very simple code.

Comment: ReactiveX is an embedded Java library that can be used to build such processor graphs. Alternatively, Spring Cloud Data flow https://dataflow.spring.io/getting-started/